# Different startup configuration for specific controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Consider the following `ConfigureServices()` inside the Startup class:

```
// ...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
    });
    // ...
}
// ...
```

Here the `SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter` will be `true` for every controller with the `[ApiController]` attribute.

But, what if I need this to be true only for specific controllers? Is this possible?

I found that we can "start" a new branch with `appBuilder.Map()` inside the `Configure()` method for a specific route path. The problem with this solution is that the `services` are still shared.

**EDIT:** `SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter` is just an example. I need to do more for specific controllers :)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/297568/how-to-suppress-suppressmodelstateinvalidfilter-at.html) on Microsoft learn.

a sample

```
 [ApiController]


public class PersonController
 {
     [SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter]
     public ActionResult<Person> Get() => new Person();
 }
    
 public class SuppressModelStateInvalidFilterAttribute : Attribute, IActionModelConvention
 {
     public void Apply(ActionModel action)
     {
         for (var i = 0; i < action.Filters.Count; i++)
         {
             if (action.Filters[i] is ModelStateInvalidFilter)
             {
                 action.Filters.RemoveAt(i);
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```